# JavaScript Quiz getting right and wrong answers not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating questions in JS, but some of my answers are not showing up because of quotes and trying to escape HTML.
I am also having trouble getting the correct user answer to give the user plus points or deductions. Right now, the code is reading every answer as incorrect.

```
Quiz.prototype.guess = function (answer) {
  if(this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {   
    right.innerHTML = "Correct!";
    this.score += 10;
  } else if (!this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
    right.innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
    wrongTimer();
  }
  this.questionIndex++;
}
```

If user is right, they get 10 points. If user chooses wrong answer, deduct 10 seconds from the timer.

[JS Quiz](https://jsfiddle.net/deannapi/nw7gpcLk/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your snippet it turns out that `answer` is just the actually clicked text.
Since the `isCorrectAnswer` checks it against the `choice` key of your question class which is ony `"1"`, `"2"` and so on it will never match.

Change your question definition like this and it should work:

```
new Question(
     "2. What company developed JavaScript?",
     ["Java Inc.",
     "Netscape",
     "JQuery",
     "CERN"],
     "Netscape"
);
```